Nuxt3 program SSR fails after deployment to server
This my config.js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  debug: true,
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0', 
    port: 3000       
  },
  ssr: true,
  target: 'server',
  modules: ['nuxt-mongoose', '@nuxt/ui', '@vant/nuxt', '@pinia/nuxt', '@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt'],
  mongoose: { 
    uri: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
  },
  css: [
    '~/assets/css/fonts.css'
  ],
  nitro: {
    port: 3000,
    logLevel: 'debug'
  },
  app: {
    head: {
       ...
    }
  }
})

And this is how I get the data

const recommends = useState('recommends', () => [])

const { data: recommendData } = await useAsyncData('recommends', () => $fetch(`/api/bookrecommendbeans/`))

if (recommendData.value && recommendData.value.length > 0) {
  recommends.value = recommendData.value
}

On my Windows and Mac computers, after I use npm build and then npm start to start the project, the browser opens to 127.0.0.1:3000, right click to view the web page source code, I was able to see that the content of the web request is embedded in the html
When I deploy to the server, although I can still request data, everything looks normal, but the content of the web request is not embedded in html,and i find error info in html
[["Reactive",1],{"data":2,"state":3,"once":9,"_errors":10,"serverRendered":6,"path":15,"pinia":16},{},{"$scolor-mode":4,"$srecommends":8},{"preference":5,"value":5,"unknown":6,"forced":7},"system",true,false,[],["Set"],{"recommends":11},["NuxtError",12],{"message":13,"statusCode":14},"[GET] "/api/bookrecommendbeans/": \u003Cno response> Response is not defined",500, "/hotbooks",{"hot":17,"clickedPage":19},{"hot":18},null,{"page":18}]

I don't understand how to solve this problem!
I tried to start the project with PM2 on the server
Tried running npm start directly from the project directory
but the result is the same
I realized that my local node version is 20.xx and the server is 16.xx (because the system version is too low to go up)
The above is what I can provide so far

After the build, you're supposed to run a preview. Because npm run start will run the dev server again. Are you using SSG or SSR also? "but the content of the web request is not embedded in HTML", you mean that it is not SSR'ed? Is it empty?

yes After deployment, I visited the site, right clicked to view the source code, and in the html section I could see this section
.
Hm? There is nothing wrong about that part AFAIK. Also this is not what matters for SSR.

kissu Thank you, I don't really understand the difference between npm start and node . /server/index.mjs. Yes, what I meant was that when I pressed CTRL + U to view the source code, I realized that the results of the network request were not merged directly into the HTML, but the request was actually successful and the page was displayed correctly

npm run start is to run a dev server, for you to code without the need to build or generate anything. The node one is to preview what you have built with npm run build. You don't really need any network request initially because it should be generated on the server on the initial rendering. A quick useful trick would be to use this extension and disable the JS on the built app that you're previewing. If your app displays well, then you don't need to worry about anything else really.

This is a good way to test, but unfortunately I found that when I turn on JavaScript switcher the content of the site will not load out, but in my local development environment 127.0.0.1:3000 is normal!

The dev server is not the concern here, we can put it aside. Check your console for any possible errors + feel free to share a public Github repo for further inspection on our side. Even tho, not sure you might need to remove some parts like the connection to mongoose. You do not have any issues or errors while building the app?

Thank u very much

I'm very happy, I found the problem today, it's really a node.js version problem, although my server supports up to 16.xx.xx, but when I lower the node version of the development environment (from 20.xx.xx to 16.xx.xx), package and deploy everything is normal, I hope it can help people with the same problem as me!
